# There are some warnings thrown with NDSolve here. How can I change my code to avoid them?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, warning-messages, nonlinear

I want to solve some differential equations, but the warnings "NDSolve change the value" are thrown. How do I change the equations?
Are there some equations that are not allowed? Are some equations wrong?

```
Clear["`*"]
n = 10;
a = CirclePoints[n];
b = 0.1;
equ = Flatten[
   Append[Table[{Sqrt[
       Subscript[y, k - 1]'[t]^2 + Subscript[x, k - 1]'[t]^2] == 
       b, (Subscript[y, k][t] - Subscript[y, k - 1][t])*
        D[Subscript[x, k - 1][t], 
         t] == (Subscript[x, k][t] - Subscript[x, k - 1][t])*
        D[Subscript[y, k - 1][t], t], 
      Subscript[y, k - 1][0] == a[[k - 1, 2]], 
      Subscript[x, k - 1][0] == a[[k - 1, 1]], 
      Subscript[y, k - 1]'[0] == b*Normalize[a[[k]] - a[[k - 1]]][[2]]
      , Subscript[x, k - 1]'[0] == 
       b*b*Normalize[a[[k]] - a[[k - 1]]][[1]]
      }, {k, 2, 
      n}], {(Subscript[y, 1][t] - Subscript[y, n][t])*
       D[Subscript[x, n][t], 
        t] == (Subscript[x, 1][t] - Subscript[x, n][t])*
       D[Subscript[y, n][t], t], Subscript[y, n][0] == a[[n, 2]], 
     Subscript[x, n][0] == a[[n, 1]], 
     Sqrt[Subscript[y, n]'[t]^2 + Subscript[x, n]'[t]^2] == b, 
     Subscript[y, n]'[0] == b*Cos[\[Pi]/n], 
     Subscript[x, n]'[0] == b*Sin[\[Pi]/n]}], 2];

sol = NDSolve[equ, 
   Flatten[{Subscript[x, #][t], Subscript[y, #][t]} & /@ Range@n, 
    2], {t, 0, 30}, MaxSteps -> 2000, SolveDelayed -> True];
result = Flatten[{Subscript[x, #][t], Subscript[y, #][t]} & /@ 
    Range@n, 2];
result = Partition[result /. sol[[1]], 2];

ParametricPlot[result, {t, 0, 30}, PlotTheme -> "Scientific", 
 PlotLabel -> "Bugs' movation", FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}]
```

Comment: Some suggestions: 1) Submit a question that captures the essence of your problem but has fewer variables.  2) Describe the difficulties you are having.  3) Do not use `Subscript` variables.  They may look nice but often  cause problems.  4) Use `Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}` instead of the obsolete `SolveDelayed -> True`.

Comment: With 20 first order ODEs and 20 variables, you have 40 boundary conditions, which may be too many.

Comment: Echoing bbgodfrey's comments, you want to present what's called a "minimal working example"—the shortest and simplest example sufficient to demonstrate the problem (see:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_working_example).  In your specific case, you'll want to find the smallest combination of variables that demonstrates the problem.  The exercise of doing this might also help you determine what's causing the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update**

Upon further examination, I noticed that the definition of `Subscript[x, k - 1]'[0]` in the question contains an extra factor of `b`, with the consequence that this initial condition is inconsistent with the ODEs,

```
Sqrt[Subscript[y, k - 1]'[t]^2 + Subscript[x, k - 1]'[t]^2] == b
```

Also, the definitions of `Subscript[x, n]'[0]` and `Subscript[y, n]'[0]` are inconsistent with the definitions of these two quantities for other values of `k`.  With these corrections, and also eliminating subscripted variables in favor of indexed variables as recommended in my comment above, yields the simplified code block

```
n = 10;
a = CirclePoints[n];
b = 0.1;
equ = Flatten@
    Table[{Sqrt[y[k]'[t]^2 + x[k]'[t]^2] == b, 
    (y[Mod[k + 1, n, 1]][t] - y[k][t])*D[x[k][t], t] == 
      (x[Mod[k + 1, n, 1]][t] - x[k][t])*D[y[k][t], t], 
    Thread[{x[k][0], y[k][0]} == a[[k]]], 
    Thread[{x[k]'[0], y[k]'[0]} == b*Normalize[a[[Mod[k + 1, n, 1]]] - a[[k]]]]}, 
    {k, 1, n}];
```

Solving the system, again in accordance with my comment above

```
sol = NDSolve[equ, Flatten[{x[#], y[#]} & /@ Range@n], {t, 0, 32}, 
    Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}] // Flatten;
```

no longer produces the warning message in the question,

> > NDSolve::ivcon  The given initial conditions were not consistent with the
> > differential-algebraic equations. NDSolve will attempt to correct the values

The resulting solution is

```
Plot[Evaluate@Through[Values[sol][t]], {t, 0, 32}, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

For completeness, two consistency tests for the initial conditions used in my answer are

```
(Partition[equ, 6][[All, ;; 2]] /. t -> 0) /. 
    (Flatten[Partition[equ, 6][[All, 3 ;;]]] /. Equal -> Rule)
(* {{True, True}, {True, True}, {True, True}, {True, True}, {True, True}, 
    {True, True}, {True, True}, {True, True}, {True, True}, {True, True}} *)

Partition[equ /. sol /. t -> 0, 6]
(* {{True, True, True, True, True, True}, {True, True, True, True, True, True}, 
    {True, True, True, True, True, True}, {True, True, True, True, True, True}, 
    {True, True, True, True, True, True}, {True, True, True, True, True, True}, 
    {True, True, True, True, True, True}, {True, True, True, True, True, True}, 
    {True, True, True, True, True, True}, {True, True, True, True, True, True}} *)
```

In contrast, corresponding consistency results for the code in the question are

```
(* {{False, False}, {False, False}, {False, False}, {False, False}, {False, True}, 
    {False, False}, {False, False}, {False, False}, {False, False}, {True, False}} *)

(* {{True, False, True, True, False, False}, {True, False, True, True, False, False}, 
    {True, False, True, True, False, False}, {True, True, True, True, True, False}, 
    {True, False, True, True, False, False}, {True, False, True, True, False, False}, 
    {True, False, True, True, False, False}, {True, False, True, True, False, False}, 
    {True, False, True, True, False, False}, {True, False, True, True, False, False}} *)
```

As an aside, I had been looking for more complicated issues, because `NDSolve` was able to produce the correct plot even with the wrong initial conditions, although with the warning message above. This seems surprising to me.

Comment: There is typo in your code on the line `Table[{Sqrt[y[k]'[t]^2 + x[k]'[t]^2 == b`, Just put `]` to close \Sqrt[]`.

Comment: @AlexTrounev  Corrected.  Thanks.

Comment: It is very nice solution (+1), but for me also it is not clear how `NDSolve` got solution with  message you are mentioned.

Comment: @AlexTrounev  In the course of investigating this problem, I tried other boundary conditions that were, in retrospect, also incorrect.  Some gave the correct output anyway (although with the warning message), others gave different answers.  Perhaps, I shall ask a question along these lines later today.  I did just add to my answer the consistency results for the question.  Thanks for your interest.  You clearly are an `NDSolve` expert.

Comment: @AlexTrounev  I now see that the ODEs plus the `{x[k][0], y[k][0]}` initial conditions uniquely determine the `{x[k]'[0], y[k]'[0]}` initial conditions up to an overall sign for each `k`.  On this basis, the ability of `DSolve` to obtain the correct solution from incorrect initial conditions does not seem so surprising.  Probably, I shall not pose a question on this matter after all.